# rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(178) [sender=3.1.2]

Tags: rsync

Today my GitHub Action workflow suddenly could not work, when I run into rsync command, shows this error:

```
Run AEnterprise/rsync-deploy@v1.0
/usr/bin/docker run --name a33c16623b7699cd84934b858311cbdd386ab_beae30 --label 8a33c1 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e JAVA_HOME_11.0.11_x64 -e JAVA_HOME -e JAVA_HOME_11_0_11_X64 -e DEPLOY_KEY -e ARGS -e SERVER_PORT -e FOLDER -e SERVER_IP -e USERNAME -e SERVER_DESTINATION -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true --network github_network_6569d291c303459885993b766ea4e6e0 -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/retire/retire":"/github/workspace" 8a33c1:6623b7699cd84934b858311cbdd386ab
Warning: Permanently added '***' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(178) [sender=3.1.2]
```

and this is my GitHub Action async part ci script:

```
   - name: Copy jar to Server
      uses: AEnterprise/rsync-deploy@v1.0
      env:
        # use pre-configured secret (the private key)
        DEPLOY_KEY: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_KEY }}
        ARGS: -avz --delete
        SERVER_PORT: "22"
        # folder to push (./ is the root of current repo)
        FOLDER: ./dolphin-post/dolphin-post-service/build/libs
        SERVER_IP: ${{ secrets.BINGQIAN_HOST }}
        USERNAME: ${{ secrets.BINGQIAN_USER }}
        SERVER_DESTINATION: /opt/apps/dolphin-post
```

why suddenlly could not work, I did not do any change of this ci script. what should I do to fix it? By the way, I have tried rerun the ci workflow for many times but still not work.

Comment: Have you reviewed the warning message and its recommended fix? "_protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?_" / "_(see the rsync man page for an explanation)_" See `man rsync` and search for `is your shell clean` for the details

Comment: try to manually connect to your server: `ssh -i <your private key file> <your user>@<yourhost> false`. If it returns any output (like any error from a wrong login shell for your newly create user) it won't work

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your `~/.bashrc` has some output, such as an `echo` statement; inspect it. For me, that caused a problem.

Comment: Please [edit] and expand your answer, to clarify what you mean exactly. It isn't terribly clear, as it currently stands.

Comment: @Greenonline I've heard of this as a possibility; see one random example at https://serverfault.com/a/328404/293440. I've edited the post to make it clearer to me; let me know if you think it can be improved further.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - it's better now after your edit. However, what I meant (I guess) was that if Aleksandr could include an example of such a problematic line, for example the line that he had had in his `.bashrc`... also, possibly, why did the line appear in the `.bashrc`? Was it always there? or was it added by the user or some other errant script (recently or around the time that the issue started to manifest itself)? I dunno, just a thought.